# Information appears when mouse pass

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display some sort of text when my mouse pass next to a button or an expander.

How could I do this in c# WPF ?

Is it like a context menu ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the ToolTip

```
<Button Content="OK" ToolTip="Saves the information and Closes the window." />
```

Comment: thank you Tony, thats what i search for ;)